# attaching a cell to focussed cell

Tags: excel

is there any way that a cell can be attached to the focus to get the value of any selleected cell any where within the sheet.

Comment: Could you describe the scenario in simple words with an example?

Comment: And how is it programming-related?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try handling the [`SelectionChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210506.aspx) event of the `Worksheet` object in question and, in the event handler, write out the value of the selection to the destination cell?

Just remember that the selection can be more than one cell so you'll need to allow for that in your code